# How to check if files committed to SVN is encoded in UTF-8 with pre-commit hooks?

Tags: svn, bash, iconv, pre-commit-hook

i'm trying to write a SVN pre-commit hook script in Linux Bash that will reject a commit if the files can not be parsed as UTF-8.

So far I have written this script:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv

# Make sure that all files to be committed are encoded in UTF-8

for FILE in $($SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS"); do
    if [$ICONV -f UTF-8 $FILE -o /dev/null]; then
        echo "Only UTF-8 files can be committed ("$FILE")" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

The problem is that iconv requires the path to the committed files (or the text in some other form), and I don't know how to get it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `svnlook cat` to get the contents of a file from a transaction:

```
$SVNLOOK cat -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 3):

By the way there is an issue in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555285/4149095) !
You need to test the result of $SVNLOOK command ($?) because the instruction "exit 1" is in a child process so the script will never block the commit :

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv

# Make sure that all files to be committed are encoded in UTF-8.
$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | while read changeline; do

    # Get just the file (not the add / update / etc. status).
    file=${changeline:4}

    # Only check source files.
    if [[ $file == *.cpp || $file == *.hpp || $file == *.c || $file == *.h ]] ; then
        $SVNLOOK cat -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" $file 2>&1 | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 >& /dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done
test $? -eq 1 && echo "Only UTF-8 files can be committed" 1>&2 && exit 1
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the script in the original question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8355035/25507), here's a pre-commit hook that puts all of this together:

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv

# Make sure that all files to be committed are encoded in UTF-8.
$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | while read changeline; do

    # Get just the file (not the add / update / etc. status).
    file=${changeline:4}

    # Only check source files.
    if [[ $file == *.cpp || $file == *.hpp || $file == *.c || $file == *.h ]] ; then
        $SVNLOOK cat -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" "$file" 2>&1 | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 >& /dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            echo "Only UTF-8 files can be committed ("$file")" 1>&2
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```